# 500 internal server error after initializing Yii 2 advanced improved template

Tags: php, yii, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to the Yii framework.

I have just installed wampserver and the new Yii improved advanced template without any problem. After running the new improved advance application I got a 500 internal server error.

This is my phpmyadmin config file:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
<IfDefine APACHE24>
Require local
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !APACHE24>
Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
</IfDefine>
php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

I have tried updating the composer but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you think the phpMyAdmin config has got to do with anything. phpMyAdmin is a application also **it is not the database server** The database server is MYSQL. Maybe you should learn to crawl before you try the high jump. Also a 500 internal server error comes from Apache anyway

Comment: So what could be the problem

Comment: Please post the recent apache log entries related to the error, so people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:just enabling rewrite_module solves the issue.

On the wamp icon click and navigate to apache->Modules and ensure that the rewrite_module is checked by checking it.